# Remove Attribution and put it somewhere else

Tags: leaflet

Obviously I want to give attribution where it's due.
However, in some cases, I the attribution gets in the way of the page design/layout (e.g. when dealing with a very small map).

Is it ok if I remove the attribution from the map either
a) entirely and give credit on a separate page (similar to smartphone apps that have a "Acknowledgements" View in their settings)
and/or
b) replace the attribution with a small link, that links directly to a separate attributions page

?

// Clarification: I'm asking for a legal perspective

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would opt for b) replace the attribution with a small link. Also from a legal perspective I feel this option would do most justice to the used data and/or map services, since it secures a link between the data and its attribution in the most direct way possible in your situation. However, I'm not a lawyer, so this is simply my own opinion based on common sense.

Another thing you can check is whether any of the used data or services describes in its terms & conditions how and where it should be attributed.

As in how to implement the option b); if you use the same attribution text for every layer you add, then Leaflet has the neat feature to show it only once. For example:

```
L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?', {
    attribution: '<a href="/attribution">Map attribution</a>'
}).addTo(map);

L.tileLayer.wms("https://mesonet.agron.iastate.edu/cgi-bin/wms/nexrad/n0r-t.cgi?", {
    layers: 'nexrad-n0r-900913',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    attribution: '<a href="/attribution">Map attribution</a>'
}).addTo(map);
```

In the attribution area on the map it will only show `Leaflet | Map attribution`, where `Map attribution` is a link to your attribution page.

Also see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jwfb2cuu/2/) for a working example.

Comment: Thanks Sidney and thanks for providing example code. However, I was asking because I am not sure what's the safe way to do it from a legal stand point. I don't want to infringe on anyones copyright, but I have to find a solution that keeps my layout in tact AND gives proper attribution :)

Comment: You're welcome Christopher. I feel that also from a legal perspective option b) would do most justice to the used data and/or map services, since it secures a link between the data and its attribution in the most direct way possible in your situation. However (disclaimer :)), I'm not a lawyer, so this is purely based on common sense. I updated my answer accordingly.